# Need a Jquery which will click randomly links in frame

Tags: jquery, random, click

I have a frame and I am visiting some websites in them. I would like jquery to randomly click links in the frame. Is it possible? If it is could anyone guide me how?

I am thinking to get a elements and randomly trigger click function. I am not sure if that would work and I would like to have elegant way to do it.

I will be glad if anyone could help me out with this problem.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Did your try with your own idea? Is it working or not?

Comment: No cos not all the pages are from the same domain. I didn't think that would work and I guess I got my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If frames from other domains than no.

For frames from same domain you can use contentDocument object and search for links in it